# How to apply/save Python WINREG changes real-time

Tags: python, winreg

```
import winreg

REG_PATH = r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer"

def set_reg(name, value):
    try:
        winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH)
        registry_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH, 0, 
                                       winreg.KEY_WRITE)
        winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, name, 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, value)
        winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
        return True
    except WindowsError:
        return False

def get_reg(name):
    try:
        registry_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH, 0,
                                       winreg.KEY_READ)
        value, regtype = winreg.QueryValueEx(registry_key, name)
        winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
        return value
    except WindowsError:
        return None


#Read value 
print (get_reg('NoLogOff'))

#Set Value (will write the value to reg, the changed val requires a win re-log to apply*)

set_reg('NoLogOff',1)

#will then apply the registry changes
```

The code above will change the NoLogOff value to 1, but will not save/apply in the actual windows registry. Is there anything I can do to have this done in real-time??

Answer (score 0):

The code **will** change the value in the Windows Registry. If you're using `regedit` you must make sure you refresh in order to view the changes.

Keep in mind many changes to the Windows Registry require a computer restart (or at least a logout from the current user) in order to reload the settings and actually apply them. This is unavoidable for most values.

If you wish to force the registry key changes on the disk and bypass the Windows lazy flush, you can use `winreg.FlushKey(registry_key)` before closing. However, It still does not guarantee the settings will apply immediately without restart, only that the registry will be saved to disk.

Comment: The only issue is, even after a restart it would seem that the value remains unchanged in the registry... Any ideas? I really appreciate the help

Comment: What happens when you try setting it manually via regedit? Does it still remain unchanged after restart? Maybe it's a permission issue? (run as admin)

Comment: When I change it manually it takes effect immediately, as I can no longer log out. I'm currently running the script via admin vscode and hope to adjust it not manually.

Comment: I am not entirely sure then, I'll have to look when I have access to a windows machine. You're sure you don't suppress any WindowsError right?

Comment: I went ahead and ran it without the try/except and It ran with no errors. good idea though